# Is it valid to use properties of Disposing object

Tags: c#, .net, using-statement

can anybody tell me if it is valid to use the properties of Disposing object ? for e.g. in the following code DataTable is getting Dispose but its property DefaultView is used later,

```
public DataView MyView { get; set; }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (DataTable table = new DataTable())
        {
            using (DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("s"))
            {
                table.Columns.Add(dc);
                MyView = table.DefaultView;

            }
            Debug.Write(table.Columns[0].ColumnName);
        }
    }
```

I don't get any error if i use MyView. but isn't it true that Disposing object dispose all its properties in this case DefaultView.

Comment: In general, don't touch an object which has been disposed. You happen to be getting away with it with `DataTable`. Don't get into the habit.

Comment: Where is it being used later? It goes out of scope outside of the `using` statement so it can't be used later.

Comment: You are 100% correct. The managed resource that the reference 'dc'  pointed to should absolutely be expected to behave the way. The reference itself is not and cannot be accessed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the type, but as a general rule you should only call `Dispose()` when you are completed done using the object. Most `IDisposable` implementations will throw an `ObjectDisposedException` if you try to access any member after disposing the object.

There's nothing inherent about `IDisposable` that forces an implementing class to invalidate all access to all members upon disposal.

Only if the type *specifically* documents that it allows you to call certain members after it's been disposed should you consider doing so. And personally, I'd try to stay away from using types that are implemented that way.

Note that this pertains to the object itself, not necessarily objects it references. That is, just because object `A` has a property that references some other object `B`, that doesn't mean that object `B` becomes invalid to use when you dispose `A`.

A good example of this would be the `NetworkStream` class, which has a `Socket` property. If you initialize the `NetworkStream` object as not owning the `Socket` instance passed to its constructor, then the `Socket` instance remains valid for use after disposing the `NetworkStream`, and this is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

The base `DataTable` and `DataColumn` classes *do* implement `IDisposable`, but their implementations don't do anything.  These implement `IDisposable` because a *derived* class may need to dispose of resources.

For instance, back in the day, I had a generic, strongly-typed DataTable class that I wrote. It did actually encapsulate the database connection, or possibly a stream. In that case, `Dispose` really did something.

Answer (score -1):

The IDisposable interface is implemented when you have unmanaged resources that could cause problems if an exception is raised before those resources are freed.

When used in a using block the compiler generates

```
try{... } 
catch{... } // may be empty, I can't recall at the moment 
finally 
{
   Dispose() ;
}
```

since the value you added was not an unmanaged resource there is no reason to assume it was disposed of. There is still a valid reference to the object, so the GC will not clear the memory.  Thinking about it, it would be far scarier if an exception *was* raised.

C# has memory management under the hood, so it's out of sight out of mind for many programmers. There are certainly some things that are implemented poorly out in the wild since resource management is not something you often think about in c#

Comment: it's not a question of when `IDisposable` is _used_. It's a question of when it is _implemented_.

Comment: well, I was only meaning to suggest that you still have a valid reference when accessing MyView. 'IDisposable' is used to free *unmanaged* resources that the GC would not know about. The reference you are calling to question is a managed resource and would not require any work to ensure proper disposal of resources, since the GC is very efficient. Is there something I am not understanding in the question?

Comment: You are not understanding a critical part of `IDisposable`. In general, if a class implements that interface, it means that the class needs you to call `Dispose()`. The usual reason for that is unmanaged resources. However, it's not a good idea to second guess the intentions of the class designers, which you seem to be doing. Tie your question back to `DataTable` and let's see if it gets better.

Comment: If the class designers intended for managed resources to be freed explicitly they are not using the interface correctly.

`Use the Dispose method of this interface to explicitly release unmanaged resources in conjunction with the garbage collector. The consumer of an object can call this method when the object is no longer needed.`


source:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx